# Creating A Struct With A Callback That Has A Generic Parameter

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a struct that can get passed to a view to create a button. In the callback, I want to be able to put in some generic type of data to be able to use it in the callback. I have the following, incorrect, struct definition:

```
struct MyButtonData<T>: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var text: String
    var color: Color
    var callback: (T) -> ()
    
    // Edited: init(text: String, color: Color, callback: @escaping (T) -> ()) {
    init(text: String, color: Color, data: T, callback: @escaping (T) -> () -> ()) {
        self.text = text
        self.color = color
        // Edited: 
        self.callback = callback(data)
    }
}
```

What I want to be able to do is to initialize it something like this:

```
/// Edited: 
myButtonData = MyButtonData(text: "Button " + $0.description, color: Color.random, data: data) { data in
    {
        print("Button \(data.description) pressed")
    }
```

where `data` is a value of some type that I just computed, and want to use to set a variable if the button is pushed. I want this to be as open as possible.

I have an <s>two</s> issue with this. <s>First, I can't use `data` in the closure, and</s> When I try to set up an array:

```
var myButtons: [MyButtonData]
```

I get an error: `Reference to generic type 'MyButtonData' requires arguments in <...>`, so I can't put my arguments in where I want to, and I can't properly set up an array with it. How do I fix my callback closure signature? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When You return T in callBack, you are losing all important data you need to use, because you are returning T which conform to nothing! Let me give you example, if your computed data is String and you are sending it as T, the receiver part has no idea what is it! So you can do 2 things, first do not use T use the thing you need like String or Double or ..., second way could be sending as an object or even Any. ps: I think you want add action code for button, So you do need use `()-> Void`, not the current way you are trying.

Comment: I figured out how to send my data in to the closure, but I can't fix the other error.